# Trying to reach 200 rep, then this bogus? edit rejection

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reject

[This](https://superuser.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/34867) edit rejection claims that I submitted this with spelling errors. There is no spelling error that I can find.

I am at 198. Obviously, I am going to go edit another so I can hit my 200.

Is there some spelling error I do not see here?:

> **Linux - stopping kernel module from automatically loading**
>
> I am using Angstrom distribution on my Overo board, and I have a little problem. Sometimes kernel modules that are used to handle my camera are loaded at boot time, sometimes not.
>
> I am wondering, is there some file where there are modules listed that should be loaded at boot time? Or is there some other way that the system knows what modules to load.
>
> Anyway, I wanted to make Linux don't load those modules automatically so I always know that I need to load them up manually.
>
> Also I wanted to disable automatic loading of a module that is used for wireless because it takes few seconds for this module to set up and most of the time I am not using wireless net on my board.

Comment: My bad - The reject reason was supposed to be "too minor"  I was simultaneously reviewing edits elsewhere.

Comment: @Nifle Okay, thanks. You did submit/accept the near identical and even more minor edit you yourself made, though.

Comment: Yep - I tend to do that (especially on relatively new questions), but I get no rep from doing it.

Comment: to note you're not quite close 200 http://superuser.com/users/155990/zero2cx?tab=reputation

Comment: @Sathya The 100 rep association bonus was just added today.

Answer (score 5):

> Anyway, I wanted to make Linux don't load those modules automatically so I always know that I need to load them up manually.

...is gramatically questionable. It should be more like

> Anyway, I wanted to stop Linux from loading those modules automatically so that I always know that I need to load them up manually.

...or something like that.

---

In general, you should avoid relatively small edits just for the sake of gaining rep. Read the whole question through in detail, and make sure you're improving it as much as possible. Does anything not quire make sense? Could you clarify something? Is the grammar and spelling all right?

Edits for editing's sake aren't useful. Make sure your edits are significant and meaningful, so that each edit is valuable.

Comment: The OP didn't introduce any spelling error though, that is the main point.

Comment: I fixed the spelling. I did not attempt to fix the questionable grammar here, as I saw the questioner's intent very clearly. If borderline grammar still passes muster, you should leave it, right? The edit was not too minor, IMO. The edit comments: `Fix title and spelling; add tag; add markdown;`. I did a lot with little tweaks. I improved it. The `Edit Rejector` user rejected my edit, then edited it __in the same manner__ but less comprehensively, leaving the title ambiguous whereas I did not. No improvement by that user at all when compared side-to-side with mine.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no spelling errors. The rejection was mistakenly attributed to spelling errors.

As an aside, the intended reason was meant to be "too trivial".

Comment: As you're responding to another answer, you should probably post this as a comment. Unlike in a traditional web forum, the order of posts is dynamic and customizable by the viewer, so this answer can show up above any other.

Comment: My intent was to answer the question asked. I did not do that? I want to leave an answer, but only if I actually answer the question. I thought I did that here. ?? I'll rethink...

Comment: I thought you already took the "bogus rejection" stance in your question, obviating the need to post it separately in an answer. My mistake.

Comment: @DanielBeck Much improved, now. Thx.